# What is the Scala way of summing fields of list of tuples?

Tags: json, scala

I want to reduce list of tuples that have a common field such as x by summing y fields.

Input:

```
List(("x" -> "foo", "y" -> 1000),
     ("x" -> "foo", "y" -> 1),
     ("x" -> "bar", "y" -> 101))
```

Output:

```
List(("x" -> "foo", "y" -> 1001),
     ("x" -> "bar", "y" -> 101))
```

What is the good approach for that? foldLeft or reduce?

Comment: What is your key to group the objects by?

Comment: In this case the value of x, `foo`.

Comment: What JSON parser do you use?

Comment: The Play Framework's JSON library.

Comment: You should use json as output format, dont't use manipulate data.

Comment: The input and output are invalid. Could you fix that please.

Comment: @blueiur Good point, thanks.

Comment: @AlexandrNikitin I think, the inputs and outputs are correct now.

Comment: This seems two entirely different questions. How to reduce/sum by key a list of tuples, and how to convert a List of tuples into JSON. Why do you think they are related?

Comment: @Paul, blueiur's comment seemed reasonable so I wanted to update the input so that the input is different from JSON. Anyway, you're right, too. We can skip JSON conversion. I will edit the question.

Comment: In which case @chengpohi has what seems a good answer

Comment: Yeah, it helped me a lot. I will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your item should be tuple:

```
List(("x" -> "foo", "y" -> 1000),("x" -> "foo", "y" -> 1), ("x" -> "bar", "y" -> 101))
```

use `groupBy` to group your key, and `mapValues` to generate the target:

```
List(("x" -> "foo", "y" -> 1000),("x" -> "foo", "y" -> 1), ("x" -> "bar", "y" -> 101))
 .groupBy(x => x._1)
 .mapValues(t => t.head._2._1 -> t.foldLeft(0.0)(_ + _._2._2))
```

The ***Output***:

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map[(String, String),(String, Double)] = 
    Map((x,foo) -> (y,1001.0), (x,bar) -> (y,101.0))
```

Comment: This seems a reasonable answer to the first part of the question. Not sure why it got a downvote